# Landing from a input field to a auto-suggest div with (keyboard) down button

Tags: jquery

There is an input field, and upon entering some characters in it, jquery shows div with search results (as an auto-suggest type). Shortly, its absolutely same thing as on FB.

Now, any clue how can I apply down button (on keyboard) to land on that div with results via jquery after div show up and user presses down button - as well to navigate throughout div with up and down keys if possible?

```
<input id="target"> //inp field
<div id ="search"> //div that show search results
```

Thx..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From a input field to a auto-suggest created div with (keyboard) down button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845645/from-a-input-field-to-a-auto-suggest-created-div-with-keyboard-down-button)

Answer (score 1):

I use [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
It allows the use of keyboard or mouse input no problems

Comment: Yes I'm sure but I dont use jquery plugins to keep JS library less heavier as possible. I just use easing as an addon. I use keyup() for auto-suggest.