# From a input field to a auto-suggest created div with (keyboard) down button

Tags: php, jquery

There is an input field, and upon entering some characters in it, jquery shows div with search results (as an auto-suggest type made by jquery core only keyup()). Shortly, this search is absolutely similar as one on FB.

Now, any clue how can I apply down button (on keyboard) to land on that div with results via jquery after div show up and user presses down button - as well to navigate throughout div with up and down keys if possible?

```
<input id="target"> //inp field
<div id ="search"> //div that show search results
```

Thx.

Comment: I think it would be better if you put the results in a <select> with some nice styling

Comment: Actually I removed <select> a month ago due to quite a lot of problems with SEO stuff and search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event "keypress" of JQuery.

```
$("#inputField").keypress(function() {
    // actions here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a nice autocomplete which does everything you want:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/